# animation-duraction depend on its width with pure css3

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

Is it possible to calc animation-duration depend on element's width with pure css?

I have a marquee animation. And I want the animation-duration depend on the length(width) of the text itself. Is it possible to deal without js?

Comment: No, not possible

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could calculate animation based on width using a CSS preprocessor, but the problem one is going to encounter is that unless the width is specified, CSS isn't going to know how wide something is.  That information doesn't become available until the page is loaded.